# \read reset command content

Tags: macros

I require to save the value of the first read line for use in the next pass of the loop. On the second read, I then want to output both the previous read line's contents and the current read line's content. e.g

Input file:
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6

Expected output:
line 1 / line 2
line 3 / line 4
line 5 / line 6

The \read in the following code resets the contents of the newcommand \firstline to be the same as the contents of the current read

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{tmp.txt}
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
\end{filecontents*}
\newread\reader
\endlinechar=-1
\newcounter{2xLines}
\newcommand\IterateLines{
    \begingroup
        \newcommand{\first}{}
        \setcounter{2xLines}{0}
        \openin\reader=./tmp.txt\relax
        \loop
            \read\reader to \line
            \unless\ifeof\reader
                \stepcounter{2xLines}
                \ifnum\the\value{2xLines}=2
                    \first / \line\par
                    \renewcommand{\first}{}
                    \setcounter{2xLines}{0}
                \else
                    \renewcommand{\first}{\line}
                \fi
        \repeat
        \closein\reader
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\IterateLines
\end{document}
```

Apologies if not correctly formatted - first post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `\renewcommand{\first}{\line}` instead of `\let\first\line`.

The difference is that the former just tell TeX to replace `\first` with `\line`; the latter defines `\first` to have the same *current* meaning of `\line`.

There are a few other improvements.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\newread\reader
\newcounter{2xLines}

\newcommand\IterateLines{%
  \begingroup
  \endlinechar=-1
  \setcounter{2xLines}{0}%
  \openin\reader=./\jobname.txt\relax
  \loop
  \read\reader to \line
  \unless\ifeof\reader
  \stepcounter{2xLines}
  \ifodd\value{2xLines}
    \let\first=\line
  \else
    \first/\line\par
  \fi
  \repeat
  \closein\reader
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}

\IterateLines

\end{document}
```

I used `\jobname` just to be sure of not clobbering my files, it's an unimportant detail. More important is that you should set `\endlinechar` only when reading the file, not globally.

Also the choice between even or odd can be made easier with `\ifodd`. Note that `\value{2xLines}` is better than `\the\value{2xLines}` in this context.

You may be interested in a different implementation using `expl3`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\IterateLines{m}
 {
  \egreg_iteratelines:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__egreg_iteratelines_seq
\ior_new:N \g__egreg_iteratelines_stream

\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_iteratelines:n
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__egreg_iteratelines_seq
  \ior_open:Nn \g__egreg_iteratelines_stream { #1 }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g__egreg_iteratelines_stream
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__egreg_iteratelines_seq { \tl_trim_spaces:n { ##1 } }
   }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 2 } { \seq_count:N \l__egreg_iteratelines_seq }
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \l__egreg_iteratelines_seq { ##1 }
    /
    \seq_item:Nn \l__egreg_iteratelines_seq { ##1 + 1 }
    \par
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\IterateLines{\jobname.txt}

\end{document}
```

The main difference is that the reading part is decoupled from the typesetting part. First I read the whole file, storing each line in a sequence. Then the sequence is read back for typesetting two items per line.

Comment: Excellent. A valuable lesson with regards the the actions of \renewcommand and \let.